# Prove or disprove: Every subgroup of the integers has finite index.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Please check my proof

I claim every subgroup of the integers has finite index

Suppose nZ is subgroup of integer

Then the cosets are

(n)+0,(n)+1,(n)+2,.......(n)+n-1

Since the cosets can't exceed (n-1)

therefore, every subgroup of integers has finite index

Comment: Check your proof with the answer of Eric Wofsey at the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful of 'edge' cases.  What about the subgroup generated by $0$?

Comment: is it infinite index?

Comment: @Lingnoi401: Think about what is the subgroup, and then what are the cosets.